# Why does Google mark messages as 'important according to our magic sauce'? Criteria?

Tags: gmail

Gmail will sometimes mark some emails as:

> Important according to our magic sauce.

[image: Screenshot]

How does this work? What *kind* of emails would get marked as "important according to our magic sauce"?

What may be some of the factors that are at play?

---

<sup>• Background: Emails that are marked as "important" by Gmail always come with a corresponding reason. Aside from "important according to our magic sauce", there are:</sup>

  > <sup>•Important mainly because of the words in the message.
  >
  >     •Important mainly because of the words in the message.
  >
  >     •Important mainly because of the people in the conversation.
  >
  >     •Important mainly because of the words in the message.
  >
  >     •Important mainly because of your interaction with messages in the conversation.
  >
  >     •Important mainly because of the words in the message.
  >
  >     •Important because you marked it important.
  >
  >     •Important mainly because of the words in the message.
  >
  >     •Important mainly because it was sent directly to you.
  >
  >     •Important mainly because of the words in the message.
  >
  >     •Important mainly because you often read messages with this label.</sup>

<sup>• [email.about.com](http://email.about.com/od/gmailtips/qt/How-To-Find-Out-Why-Gmail-Categorized-A-Message-As-Important.htm) has some vague piece of information:</sup>

  > <sup>*Important according to our magic sauce.* — You may see this for older messages marked as important.</sup>

<sup>• Search links:

    • *[Gmail important according to our magic OR secret "sauce"](http://google.com/search?q=gmail%20important%20according%20to%20our%20magic%20OR%20secret%20%22sauce%22)* (Google)

    • *[Sauce](https://support.google.com/mail/search?q=sauce)* (Gmail support)

    • *[Important](https://support.google.com/mail/search?q=important)* (Gmail support)</sup>

---

Updated Dec 2019 - It now says, 'Important according to Google magic'.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is inviting a discussion of speculation and conjecture.

Answer (score 14):

It's just cute marketing-speak. Google's algorithms have determined that the message might be important based on whatever secret stuff the algorithm contains. It's either too close to industrial secrets or so esoteric it can't be briefly explained.

Comment: I'm aware it's marketing-speak... I mean what exactly might those *stuff* be. (will edit to make this point clear)

Comment: All we could possibly do is guess. Only Google knows, and they're not telling.

Comment: Yea, Google won't say that's for sure. The only way for an answer is through the [*crowd*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crowdsourcing) e.g. someone with an educated guess and some controlled tests.

Comment: That, I'm afraid, is not what this site is for.

Comment: SE is the platform for crowdsourced answers. That's the very definition of crowdsource. SE's raison detre is "because the manual is insufficient".

Comment: Yes, for answers that are verifiably and objectively correct. Batting around a bunch of guesses to see what makes senses really isn't what these sites are for.

Comment: The mentioned keyword is "controlled tests". Answers based on tests are not guesses. It's the exact  same thing with the scientific method, we start with    [educated guesses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_method#Hypothesis_development) and work from there. All [~20m answers](http://stackexchange.com/sites#questions) excluding *spam* share one thing in common: they are the result of a process which involves guesses. This will hold true for the next 20m answers too, so long as bugs continue to exist in code and manuals.